# MDT messed up BCD file settings/location when PXE booting, error 0xc000000f

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, mdt, mdt-2012, bcdedit

I have a MDT setup here which worked fine until I updated the Windows image to 1903 recently and made some other changes.

Now the PXE boot on clients fails with error "0xc000000f", missing boot configuration data files in folder \Tmp\ of the remote installation share. File names are `<architecture>{<some UUID>}.bcd`, e.g. `x64uefi{ABC-XYZ-...}.bcd`.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzArU.png).

When the BCD files in Tmp\ are freshly generated, PXE Boot works, but the folder is cleared periodically and then PXE boot will fail with above error.

The files are generated after e.g. replacing the boot images in the MDT configuration, or when restarting the MDT services. I also should add that I've set up a distributed environment and the remote installation folder is replicated to other servers via DFS-R. That shouldn't affect this problem though.

**My question is: Where can I configure the location of the BCD files? Because `Tmp\xyz.bcd` is not the default location, but `\Boot\BCD` is as seen [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/528421/error-loading-my-bcd-when-trying-to-pxe-boot-to-windows-pe). The location hast to be set somewhere dynamically, as the UIDs change everytime and the filename in the bluescreen points to the new BCD file.**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
The solution was to exclude the tmp/ folder from DFS-R (replication).

So... somehow this seems to be solved so far, the problem is that I changed so many variables that I don't know which actually solved the problem, but it is one of the following:

- `wdsutil /uninitialize-server`, the reconfigure
- completely recreate the WDS/RemoteInstallation share
- completely reassign/recreate permissions for the whole folder

Also did some other things that I wouldn't consider relevant for the solution to the problem.